# Can I use AR object as hash key or should I use object_id instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Because of Ruby awesomeness it is possible to use any object as key

```
document = Document.find 1
o = Hash.new
o[1] = true
o[:coool] = 'it is'
o[document] = true
# an it works

o[document]
#=> true
```

but just because it is possible doesn't mean is good practice

However I have situation where in my controller I need to set something similar, so I can loop trough it in view

```
#controller
@users_with_things = Hash.new
Things.accessible_by(some_curent_user_logic).each do |thing|
  @user_with_things[thing.user] ||= Array.new
  @user_with_things[thing.user] <<  thing.id
end 

#view
- @users_with_things.each do |user, thing_ids|
  %input{type: :checkbox, name: "blank[user_#{user.id}]", value: 1, class: "select_groups", :'data-resource-ids' => "[#{thing_ids.join(',')}]", :'data-user-type' => user.type }
```

The reason why I want to do it this way is because I don't want to call from my view `User.find_by_id`  (want to make it clean)

```
#controller
@users_with_things = Hash.new
Things.accessible_by(some_curent_user_logic).each do |thing|
  @user_with_things[thing.user.id] ||= Array.new
  @user_with_things[thing.user.id] <<  thing.id
end 

#view
- @users_with_things.each do |user_id, thing_ids|
  - user = User.find user_id
  %input{type: :checkbox, name: "blank[user_#{user.id}]", value: 1, class: "select_groups", :'data-resource-ids' => "[#{thing_ids.join(',')}]", :'data-user-type' => user.type }
```

So my 1st question is: **is it ok to use ActiveRecord object as Hash key in situation like this**

I can imagine several scenarios where this may go wrong (sessions, when object changes in model and so on) however this is just for rendering in a view

### Alternative !

so this is one way to do it, the other may be like this

```
#controller
@users_with_things = Hash.new
Things.accessible_by(some_curent_user_logic).each do |thing|
  @user_with_things[thing.user.object_id] ||= Array.new
  @user_with_things[thing.user.object_id] <<  thing.id
end 

#view
- @users_with_things.each do |user_object_id, thing_ids|
  - user = ObjectSpace._id2ref(user_object_id)  #this will find user object from object_id
  %input{type: :checkbox, name: "blank[user_#{user.id}]", value: 1, class: "select_groups", :'data-resource-ids' => "[#{thing_ids.join(',')}]"", :'data-user-type' => user.type }
```

...which is even more, hardcore. However it is way around if for some reason `hash[ARobject] = :something` would create big memory cluster for some reason

question 2 : **is it good idea to do it this way ?**

---

to be complete there is also another alternative and that is

```
# ...
@user_with_thing[ [thing.user.id, thing.user.type] ] << thing_id
# ...
```

so basically array object will be key

```
@user_with_thing[ [1, 'Admin'] ] 
#=> [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think to use a hash is a good way to organise in your situation. However, I would advise against using the user or to big an object as hash keys, simply because it renders your hash unreadable and because it is really only this sole object with it's object id that can be used as a key.

```
o = Object.new
h = { o => 'something' }
h[Object.new] #=> nil
```

In your situation, this may not be an issue, because you simply need to iterate it. But it may be a shot in the leg as soon as you want to do something else with that hash, or you have different instances of the same Active Record Data (which is very common in Rails applications, unless you are a really paying attention what gets loaded when). Besides that, I think it is good to stick by the widely used convention to use simple objects (strings, symbols) as hash keys to make your code readable and maintainable.

Maybe it would be best to keep a two-dimensional hash, like this:

```
@users_with_things = Things.accessible_by(some_curent_user_logic).inject({}) do |a, thing|
  user_id = thing.user.id
  a[user_id] ||= { :user => thing.user, :things => [] }
  a[user_id][:thing] << thing
  a
end
```

Then you can iterate over `@users_with_things` in your view like this:

```
@users_with_things.each do |user_id, values|
  # values[:user] is the user, values[:things] the array of things
```

Comment: hmmm, your example  is actually nice idea (+1 & ✔ for that), I also agree that my solution is "dangerous" and I wouldn't use it in logic if I would do more than just iterate :)